# How to wire a single phase, 3 wire motor?

Tags: wiring, ac-motor

So i bought a motor off of kijiji, it was an old furnace motor. I am trying to build a flat lapidary machine and use this motor to power it. However, there is no wiring diagram on the motor anywhere and i cannot figure out which wires connect to what. Everything i find online says they have 3 wires plus a white ground motor, however this motor only has a blue, red and black wire coming out of it. I *think* that the black wire is the ground wire. i literally just want to connect it to a switch & a power source which i think should be really simple... thank you for any advice/wisdom you may have to offer
[motor label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74TUT.jpg)

[image: wiring in motor]

Comment: Speak with the seller and always check that what is being sold online has sufficient documents to support it. That's my advice/wisdom.

Comment: " i literally just want to connect it to a switch & a power source which i think should be really simple" It is not that simple. Most single-phase motors that size require a capacitor. If it is not attached, it must be in the furnace or lost. The motor label may state the value, but I can not read it well enough. Wire color use in not sufficiently consistent to use for reliable connections.